# Python: Class method vs function gives different results

Tags: python

I've encountered a problem when using classes and their methods for performing calculations as opposed to functions. The implementation of the class and its methods match the functions one to one but give slightly different results:

```
import numpy as np

class Vasicek:

    def __init__(self, a, b, sigma):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.sigma = sigma

    def _calc_A(self, t):
        B = self._calc_B(t)
        return (self.b - self.sigma ** 2 / (2 * self.a ** 2)) * (t - B) - self.sigma ** 2 * B ** 2 / (4 * self.a)

    def _calc_B(self, t):
        return (1 - np.exp(-self.a * t)) / self.a

    def calc_zcb(self, r0, t):
        return np.exp(-self._calc_A(t) - self._calc_B(t) * r0)


def calc_A(a, b, sigma, t):
    B = calc_B(a, b, sigma, t)
    return (b - sigma ** 2 / (2 * a ** 2)) * (t - B) - sigma ** 2 * B ** 2 / (4 * a)

def calc_B(a, b, sigma, t):
    return (1 - np.exp(-a * t)) / a

def calc_zcb(a, b, sigma, t, r0):
    return np.exp(-calc_A(a, b, sigma, t)-calc_B(a, b, sigma, t)*r0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 0.86
    b = 0.09
    sigma = 0.0148
    r0 = 0.08
    T = 1.0
    dt = 0.25
    n = int(T / dt - 1)
    t = np.linspace(dt, T, n + 1, True)

    mld = Vasicek(a, b, sigma)
    zcb = mld.calc_zcb(t, r0)
    print(zcb) # [0.9806214  0.96185041 0.94343874 0.9253795 ]

    zcb_2 = calc_zcb(a, b, sigma, t, r0)
    print(zcb_2) # [0.97995997 0.95991382 0.93995418 0.92015313]
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

> The implementation of the class and its methods match the functions one to one

They don't match one to one:

You have

```
class Vasicek:
    ...
    def calc_zcb(self, r0, t):
        ...
```

but call it as

```
zcb = mld.calc_zcb(t, r0)
```

Reverse the two arguments and you're fine:

```
zcb = mld.calc_zcb(r0, t)
```

Nothing to do with classes versus functions. Just a silly oversight, which could have been easily debugged with some print functions.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. But thanks for pointing this out!